# JSF, Spring, and the PreRenderViewEvent

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to integrate Spring 3 into a JSF 2 project. I [registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422969/spring-faces-without-spring-flow) the SpringBeanFacesELResolver in the faces-config.xml and I added two listeners to the web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Most views and backing-beans are just working, but unfortunately, the `javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent` ceased to function. I have been using this event to call a method in the backing-bean before the view is rendered:

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent"
        listener="#{locationBean.preRenderView}" />
</ui:define>
```

With Spring 3 in place for bean creation, the `preRenderView` method is no longer called. I'd greatly appreciate any hint on what I might be doing wrong or missing!

**Update:**

In the same view, I'm trying to bind a parameter to a property of the backing-bean like this:

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{locationBean.id}" label="id" />
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

This also used to work using "pure" JSF 2 but fails to do anything using Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really spring related but as far as I know the `f:metadata` tag has to be contained inside the template client and be inserted directly inside `f:view`. An example can be found at [JSFAtWork](http://jsfatwork.irian.at/book_de/advanced_jsf.html#!idx:/advanced_jsf.html%3asec%3ametadata-position). The link is in german but I hope the code examples are clear.

Your code would have to look like this

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadate>
        <f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent"
            listener="#{locationBean.preRenderView}" />
    </f:metadate>
</ui:define>
```

With the following template

```
<f:view>
    <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
    ...
</f:view>
```

Comment: D'oh! You are so right and surely earned the credit. The event listener is working fine, now. Unfortunately, the <f:viewParam> still doesn't seem to have any effect (locationBean.id is always 0 when preRenderView is called). Any ideas on that?