# Disadvantages of using JSF+Spring without webflow

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

in following examples of JSF Spring integration, i can see that the examples makes a normal integration between spring and JSF without using webflow, so is there are any problems or issues when using Spring with JSF without using webflow, and what are the advantages of using webflow with JSF, please advise.

links:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

Comment: This post, while a little old, might shed some light on your question: http://blog.springsource.com/2007/04/21/what-spring-web-flow-offers-jsf-developers/

Comment: i need the other way around, the problems if using spring & JSF without webflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the decision whether to use WebFlow is based on your UI requirements....and if JSF is in the box, too, the only reason to actually use WebFlow is if you'd have a vast amount of "wizard-like" UI forms whose plumbing could be more elegantly handled by WebFlow (rather than JSF faces-context navigation rules).

The level of pain could also vary between different JSF implementation. For example, we've had nothing but trouble trying to integrate WebFlow 2.0.4 with IceFaces 1.8.2 (which is based on JSF 1.2).

More on that (together with a straightforward explanation on how to integrate JSF and Spring) can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422969/spring-faces-without-spring-flow/6441880#6441880) SO thread.