# JSF/Spring Session is shared between users

Tags: spring, session, jsf

I have a JSF-managed session-scopped bean. It is also a spring component so that I can inject some fields:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@Component
public class EpgBean {...}
```

The problem is that the session is shared between users! If a user does some stuff and another user from another computer connects, he sees the SessionScoped data of the other user.

Is it due to the spring @Component which would force the bean to be a singleton? What is a correct approach to this matter?

Comment: I don't use Spring, but you should theoretically get rid of those unused JSF managed bean annotations (as that would only confuse you; they are not been used at all if you use another framework to manage the beans) and add a Spring specific scope annotation, something like `@Scope("session")` or so (it indeed defaults to "application" scope, like as that JSF defaults to "none" scope when no JSF specific scope annotation is declared).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem using spring scope annotation `@Scope("session"`) instead of JSF `@SessionScopped`. I guess that since spring is configured as FacesEl resolver, it is spring scope that matters, while JSF scope is ignored.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could mark this post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I use is to keep the managed beans inside JSF container, and inject the Spring beans into them via EL on a managed property. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814535/integrating-jsf-with-spring).

To do that, set up [SpringBeanFacesELResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf-springbeanfaceselresolver) in `faces-config.xml`, so JSF EL can resolve Spring beans:

```
<application>
    ...
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    ...
</application>
```

After that, you can inject Spring beans in your @ManagedBean annotated beans like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeMB {
    // this will inject Spring bean with id someSpringService
    @ManagedProperty("#{someSpringService}")
    private SomeSpringService someSpringService;

    // getter and setter for managed-property
    public void setSomeSpringService(SomeSpringService s){
        this.someSpringService = s;
    }
    public SomeSpringService getSomeSpringService(){
        return this.someSpringService;
    }
}
```

There may be better approachs than this, but this is what I've been using lately.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about using the ManagedProperty. However I believe my original approach (declaring as spring component) is better, because you don't have to explicitly write the names of the injected beans through EL, as you can autowire them.